# Typechecking nested screen props in react navigation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

Inside the HomeScreen.tsx I get a typescript compiler error. I am of the opinion that I am currently making a mistake in the definition of the parent navigations, i.e. TabNavigation and AuthStack. But unfortunately I don't see an example in the documentation how to navigate from one nested screen to another nested screen including correct typescript syntax.

**Here you can see my error in VSCode:**

[image]

The **navigation basically works**, but the Typescript Error does not go away.

```js
// RootStack.tsx

import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import TabNavigation, {TabParamList} from './TabNavigation';
import AuthStack, {AuthStackParamList} from './AuthStack';
import {NavigatorScreenParams} from '@react-navigation/native';

export type RootStackParamList = {
  Tabs: NavigatorScreenParams<TabParamList>;
  Auth: NavigatorScreenParams<AuthStackParamList>;
};

const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

const RootStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Tabs" component={TabNavigation} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Auth"
        component={AuthStack}
        options={{presentation: 'modal'}}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default RootStack;
```

```js
// TabNavigation.tsx

import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/home';
import {
  GiftIcon,
  HomeIcon,
  MapIcon,
  NewspaperIcon,
  TicketIcon,
} from 'react-native-heroicons/outline';
import Text from '../components/Text';
import CouponStack from './CouponStack';
import TicketsScreen from '../screens/tickets';
import NewsScreen from '../screens/news';
import LocationScreen from '../screens/location';
import {useTheme} from 'styled-components/native';

export type TabParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  CouponStack: undefined;
  Tickets: undefined;
  News: undefined;
  Location: undefined;
};

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator<TabParamList>();

const TabNavigation = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
            <>
              <HomeIcon
                color={focused ? theme.colors.buttercup[500] : '#8F989D'}
                strokeWidth={2}
              />
              <Text
                fontFamily={'medium'}
                fontSize={'10px'}
                color={focused ? theme.colors.buttercup[500] : '#8F989D'}>
                Home
              </Text>
            </>
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="CouponStack"
        component={CouponStack}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
            <>
              <GiftIcon
                color={focused ? theme.colors.buttercup[500] : '#8F989D'}
                strokeWidth={2}
              />
              <Text
                fontFamily={'medium'}
                fontSize={'10px'}
                color={focused ? theme.colors.buttercup[500] : '#8F989D'}>
                Coupons
              </Text>
            </>
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Tickets"
        component={TicketsScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
            <>
              <TicketIcon
                color={focused ? theme.colors.buttercup[500] : '#8F989D'}
                strokeWidth={2}
              />
              <Text
                fontFamily={'medium'}
                fontSize={'10px'}
                color={focused ? theme.colors.buttercup[500] : '#8F989D'}>
                Tickets
              </Text>
            </>
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="News"
        component={NewsScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
            <>
              <NewspaperIcon
                color={focused ? theme.colors.buttercup[500] : '#8F989D'}
                strokeWidth={2}
              />
              <Text
                fontFamily={'medium'}
                fontSize={'10px'}
                color={focused ? theme.colors.buttercup[500] : '#8F989D'}>
                News
              </Text>
            </>
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Location"
        component={LocationScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
            <>
              <MapIcon
                color={focused ? '#f59a16' : '#8F989D'}
                strokeWidth={2}
              />
              <Text
                fontFamily={'medium'}
                fontSize={'10px'}
                color={focused ? '#f59a16' : '#8F989D'}>
                Location
              </Text>
            </>
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default TabNavigation;
```

```js
// HomeScreen.tsx

import {SafeAreaView, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image';

import Header from '../../components/Header';
import Box from '../../components/Box';
import Text from '../../components/Text';
import Membercard from '../../components/Membercard';
import {StackScreenProps} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {TabParamList} from '../../navigation/TabNavigation';

type HomeScreenProps = StackScreenProps<TabParamList, 'Home'>;

const HomeScreen = ({navigation}: HomeScreenProps) => {
  const handleLogin = () => {
    // Here I have the typescript compiler error. How can I fix this?
    navigation.navigate('Auth', {screen: 'Login'});
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
      <ScrollView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic">
        
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: What does the error say?